# Integrating glc within package for capturing video

Tags: ros, video, opengl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'd like to use glc ( http://www.ros.org/wiki/RecordingOpenGLAppsWithGLC ) to capture video from an OpenGL window from within a ROS package. There are instructions for running glc separately from the terminal, but I'd like to integrate it into my code. Has anyone done this? Are there any examples out there? Just wondering whether it's feasible, or if I should go the glReadPixels route.

Thanks
~Robin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9635/integrating-glc-within-package-for-capturing-video/) by [Robin](https://answers.ros.org/users/148/robin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2011-04-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote a function that calls glReadPixels and outputs an IplImage that is published on a topic, this is part of my openGL program. This is actually very easy to implement in your own program.

As GLC is a wrapper it should be possible to adjust GLC and input it in a rosnode. I assume you want the argument program to be inputted as a parameter. Personally I went for the readpixels path as I didn't see a use-case for this approach.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1